# ElementTree TypeError "write() argument must be str, not bytes" in Python3

Tags: python, svg, elementtree

Got a Problem with generating a .SVG File with Python3 and ElementTree.

```
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
    doc = et.Element('svg', width='480', height='360', version='1.1', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')

    #Doing things with et and doc

    f = open('sample.svg', 'w')
    f.write('<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n')
    f.write('<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\"\n')
    f.write('\"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n')
    f.write(et.tostring(doc))
    f.close()
```

The Function et.tostring(doc) generates the TypeError "write() argument must be str, not bytes". I don't understand that behavior, "et" should convert the ElementTree-Element into a string? It works in python2, but not in python3. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? See [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and search for `tostring`. Does that help?

Comment: not really, it should be decoded already in utf-8 bytestring, but python3 seems to have a problem with that

Comment: Primary cause is Python lazy "dynamic typing" mess. This code (which doesn't specify output encoding in `open()` as it should) writes to the file in **text mode**. But `ElementTree.write()` wants binmode and indeed `et.toString()` returns bytes (typing!). The encoding for what will be "XML text" must be given to `ElementTree.write()` instead! This is due to the XML header (which here is written in the second line, but should not) which is written by `ET.ElementTree` if `'xml_declaration' = True` which contains the encoding's name! It think that is called "non-transparency of lower layers".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As it turns out, `tostring`, *despite its name*, really *does* return an object whose type is `bytes`.

Stranger things have happened. Anyway, here's the proof:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, tostring
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> element = ET.fromstring("<a></a>")
>>> type(tostring(element))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Silly, isn't it?

Fortunately you can do this:

```
>>> type(tostring(element, encoding="unicode"))
<class 'str'>
```

Yes, we all thought the ridiculousness of bytes and that ancient, forty-plus-year-old-and-obsolete encoding called `ascii` was dead.

And don't get me started on the fact that they call `"unicode"` an *encoding*!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It was fun to test out. I couldn't believe it when I saw the result of `type(tostring(element))`. And then seeing the result change because of a change to a parameter value. Wow. That was really weird. Nice question.

Comment: I don't see why bytes are "ridiculous"? ASCII is in no way obsolete, though restricting oneself to 7 bit is kinda old-school, it's true. Also the `unicode` keyword is not indicating an "encoding". The semantics is, if the call attribute "encoding" is `unicode`, then **do not do any encoding**, just return a Python string (which does not have any encoding). Properly there should be two methods: `to_string()` (yields character stream without encoding) and `to_binary()` (yields byte stream with the desired encoding) to make this API clean.

Answer (score 11):

The output file should be in binary mode.

```
f = open('sample.svg', 'wb')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
f.write(et.tostring(doc).decode(encoding))
```

Example:

```
f.write(et.tostring(doc).decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify encoding of string while writing the xml file.

Like `decode(UTF-8)` with `write()`.
Example: `file.write(etree.tostring(doc).decode(UTF-8))`

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the easiest to create first some template xml (just defining the root) and then parse it...

```
docXml = ET.parse('template.xml')
root = docXml.getroot()
```

then doing what I wanted to do in my xml and them print it...

```
docXml.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```