# "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes" when trying to write an ElementTree to an XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to write some XML as a byte string (to wit, a response from the Zillow API) to an XML file using the [`ElementTree.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

content = b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Comps:comps xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/Comps.xsd https://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/b20c067/static/xsd/Comps.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:Comps="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/Comps.xsd"><request><zpid>48789177</zpid><count>1</count></request><message><text>Request successfully processed</text><code>0</code></message><response><properties><principal><zpid>48789177</zpid><links><homedetails>https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1614-E-Columbia-St-Seattle-WA-98122/48789177_zpid/</homedetails><graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1614-E-Columbia-St-Seattle-WA-98122/48789177_zpid/#charts-and-data</graphsanddata><mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/48789177_zpid/</mapthishome><comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/48789177_zpid/</comparables></links><address><street>1614 E Columbia St</street><zipcode>98122</zipcode><city>SEATTLE</city><state>WA</state><latitude>47.609388</latitude><longitude>-122.310834</longitude></address><taxAssessmentYear>2016</taxAssessmentYear><taxAssessment>528000.0</taxAssessment><yearBuilt>1907</yearBuilt><lotSizeSqFt>2613</lotSizeSqFt><finishedSqFt>2430</finishedSqFt><bathrooms>2.0</bathrooms><bedrooms>4</bedrooms><zestimate><amount currency="USD">900186</amount><last-updated>04/13/2018</last-updated><oneWeekChange deprecated="true"></oneWeekChange><valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">112285</valueChange><valuationRange><low currency="USD">783162</low><high currency="USD">1053218</high></valuationRange><percentile>90</percentile></zestimate><localRealEstate><region name="Minor" id="271921" type="neighborhood"><zindexValue>588,800</zindexValue><links><overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-Seattle/Minor/r_271921/</overview><forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/minor-seattle-wa/fsbo/</forSaleByOwner><forSale>http://www.zillow.com/minor-seattle-wa/</forSale></links></region></localRealEstate></principal><comparables><comp score="7.0"><zpid>89822967</zpid><links><homedetails>https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1711-E-Fir-St-Seattle-WA-98122/89822967_zpid/</homedetails><graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1711-E-Fir-St-Seattle-WA-98122/89822967_zpid/#charts-and-data</graphsanddata><mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/89822967_zpid/</mapthishome><comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/89822967_zpid/</comparables></links><address><street>1711 E Fir St</street><zipcode>98122</zipcode><city>SEATTLE</city><state>WA</state><latitude>47.602463</latitude><longitude>-122.309743</longitude></address><taxAssessmentYear>2016</taxAssessmentYear><taxAssessment>513000.0</taxAssessment><yearBuilt>2008</yearBuilt><lotSizeSqFt>1306</lotSizeSqFt><finishedSqFt>1490</finishedSqFt><bathrooms>3.0</bathrooms><bedrooms>3</bedrooms><lastSoldDate>03/15/2018</lastSoldDate><lastSoldPrice currency="USD">783000</lastSoldPrice><zestimate><amount currency="USD">791686</amount><last-updated>04/13/2018</last-updated><oneWeekChange deprecated="true"></oneWeekChange><valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">-8370</valueChange><valuationRange><low currency="USD">752102</low><high currency="USD">831270</high></valuationRange><percentile>87</percentile></zestimate><localRealEstate><region name="Minor" id="271921" type="neighborhood"><zindexValue>588,800</zindexValue><links><overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-Seattle/Minor/r_271921/</overview><forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/minor-seattle-wa/fsbo/</forSaleByOwner><forSale>http://www.zillow.com/minor-seattle-wa/</forSale></links></region></localRealEstate></comp></comparables></properties></response></Comps:comps><!-- H:042  T:99ms  S:2011  R:Sun Apr 15 09:01:05 PDT 2018  B:5.0.53029.1-hotfix_ADAT-2519.69881bc~hotfix-platform-for-2018-04-11.319b04e -->'
root = ElementTree.fromstring(content)
tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(root)

with open(f"comparables.xml", 'w+') as fp:
    tree.write(fp)
```

However, if I run this (in iPython) I get a `TypeError`:

```
In [3]: exec(open('zillow_api.py').read())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-23b53830497c> in <module>()
----> 1 exec(open('zillow_api.py').read())

<string> in <module>()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in write(self, file_or_filename, encoding, xml_declaration, default_namespace, method, short_empty_elements)
    774                 serialize = _serialize[method]
    775                 serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
--> 776                           short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
    777 
    778     def write_c14n(self, file):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     86         if type is None:
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:
     90                 return False

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in _get_writer(file_or_filename, encoding)
    833                 # destroyed
    834                 stack.callback(file.detach)
--> 835                 yield file.write
    836 
    837 def _namespaces(elem, default_namespace=None):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, *exc_details)
    378                 # set-up context
    379                 fixed_ctx = exc_details[1].__context__
--> 380                 raise exc_details[1]
    381             except BaseException:
    382                 exc_details[1].__context__ = fixed_ctx

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, *exc_details)
    363             cb = self._exit_callbacks.pop()
    364             try:
--> 365                 if cb(*exc_details):
    366                     suppressed_exc = True
    367                     pending_raise = False

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in _exit_wrapper(exc_type, exc, tb)
    312         """
    313         def _exit_wrapper(exc_type, exc, tb):
--> 314             callback(*args, **kwds)
    315         # We changed the signature, so using @wraps is not appropriate, but
    316         # setting __wrapped__ may still help with introspection

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Is what I'm passing in not a "file object opened for writing" as specified in the docs?

I've tried following the solution in [ElementTree TypeError "write() argument must be str, not bytes" in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480442/elementtree-typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-bytes-in-python3), but the `tostring` method appears to no longer be contained in the `xml.etree` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the argument to `tree.write()` should just be the name of the file you want to create:

```
tree.write("comparables.xml")
```

which creates `comparables.xml` in my current directory.